# How to combine multiple loss and accuracy during training in Keras?

Tags: keras, output, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

With reference to the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60264360/how-to-design-a-shared-weight-multi-input-output-auto-encoder-network), during training I am getting multiple losses and accuracies. For example,

```
Epoch 1/100
1382/1382 [==============================] - 694s 502ms/step - loss: 0.6798 - decoder_loss: 0.3399 - decoder_accuracy: 0.5770 - decoder_accuracy_1: 0.5770 - val_loss: 0.6606 - val_decoder_loss: 0.3373 - val_decoder_accuracy: 0.5783 - val_decoder_accuracy_1: 0.5783
```

It's hard to understand and what I want is only loss, accuracy, validation_loss and validation_accuracy. Is there any way to merge them.

Another thing is my log file is getting bigger and bigger as the network print the loss/accuracy after each step as:

```
1/1382 [..............................] - ETA: 13:59 - loss: 0.7226 - decoder_loss: 0.3613 - decoder_accuracy: 0.5536 - decoder_accuracy_1: 0.5536
2/1382 [..............................] - ETA: 10:23 - loss: 0.7204 - decoder_loss: 0.3602 - decoder_accuracy: 0.5881 - decoder_accuracy_1: 0.5881
3/1382 [..............................] - ETA: 8:57 - loss: 0.7151 - decoder_loss: 0.3576 - decoder_accuracy: 0.5821 - decoder_accuracy_1: 0.5821
```

Can I reduce it to output only when the epoch ends instead of each step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i assume you use the fit funciton of keras with a verbose of 1.
E.g.

```
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size = 32, epochs = 100, verbose=1)
```

You can change the verbose to 2 then you will get only one output per epoch. Alternatively you can turn the training progress output off if you set verbose to 0.
(Source: [Keras API](https://keras.io/models/model/))
E.g.

```
model.fit(Xtrain, Ytrain, batch_size = 32, epochs = 5, verbose=2)
```

Should give you an output like:
[image]

I hope this solves your problem. If not you might want to share a little bit of your code so we can help you futher.

**EDIT1:**
As for your question if you can influence your monitoring metrics: Yes you can, but I can only answer your question with assumptions because I don't have your code.
If you use keras for your model you should have used the "compile" funciton of keras somewhere. E.g

```
model.compile(optimizer=keras.optimizers.RMSprop(),  # Optimizer
          # Loss function to minimize
          loss=keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(from_logits=True),
          # List of metrics to monitor
          metrics=["accuracy"])
```

You can influence the metrics which are shown in your console if you change the metrics values to the values you want to see. (Source:[Kearas API](https://keras.io/models/model/),[Keras Metrics](https://keras.io/metrics/))

If you only want to see the `loss, accuracy` you can use the example above. The metrics `val_...` will be generated accordingly if you use a validation _split or `validation_datat` in your `fit` function. E.g.

```
history = model.fit(x_train, y_train,
                batch_size=64,
                epochs=3,
                # We pass some validation for
                # monitoring validation loss and metrics
                # at the end of each epoch
                validation_data=(x_val, y_val))
```

If build you two examples to visualize my point
 Example 1 shows `accuracy, loss, val_acc` and `val_loss`
[image: Example 1]
 Example 2 shows `accuracy, loss,mae, val_acc, val_loss` and `val_mae`
[image: Example 2]

For completness here the link to the colab notebook, where you can see my code:[Colab for Examples](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1I52UMc1R4uBuenqOPkkIl4GqVdOEG3D-)

I hope this helps to solve your quesion completly. If not let me know.

Comment: It worked! Although, the first part is still un-answered!

Comment: Glad it worked. Sorry I didn't read your question correct. I will edit my answer.